# How to remove last character from a string inside a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to print the different category's selected in a single line in xml,
like

```
<cat_name>meeting, food and drinks, sports</cat_name>
```

The output I am getting:

```
<cat_name>meeting, food and drinks, sports,</cat_name>
```

I want to remove only the last comma.

The code I have written so far is:

```
$sq="
    select category_main.cat_name
    from category_main
    join category 
        on(category.cat_id=category_main.cat_id)
    where category.event_id='$event_id'
";
$e=mysql_query($sq);

$xml ='<cat_name>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($e))
{
    $res=$row['cat_name'];

    //$new = substr($val,0,-1);
    $xml .="$res, ";                
}

$xml .='</cat_name>';
echo $xml;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`trim()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.trim.php) with the optional second parameter as a `','`

```
trim($cat_name, ',')
```

However, since you're doing this in a while loop, you should build an array then `implode()` it rather than building the string in the loop. This avoids the extra comma to begin with.

```
$arr = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($e))
{
  $arr[] = $row['cat_name'];
}
$cat_name = implode(",", $arr);
// $cat_name is now "meeting, food and drinks, sports"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [i used my variable]

```
$str = substr($str,0, (strlen($str)-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a rtrim, `rtrim( $cat , ',' )` http://php.net/rtrim